# Underfloor heating in bathroom Floor not heating

Tags: heating

Pipes in screed osb board over it and floor is tiled  .Tiles’s not heating up great any ideas

Answer (score 0):

With the pipes under the screed osb board you will not get much heat. This will act as an insulator. When I did mine I placed the PEX tubing on the board then covered it with cement and attached the tile to that. There is 8" of foam under the board to keep the heat in.

Answer (score 0):

Check the flow in the pipes, see if there is any trapped air that needs to be bled out.